What's the point with declaring a string with * or []?
I cannot understand the point with * and [] cause when reading courses on the internet, I come across things such like :

This only applies to character strings (i.e. the char* type, which can also be written as char[] ). For other array types, you're always obliged to retain the size of the array somewhere.

In a nutshell, for strings, * would be equivalent to [].
Now I have to code a simple programme reversing a string but when I declare my string with [], everything is okay, but with *, it returns me a segmentation fault. So I really need your explanations about something that looks as a nonsense for me.
Here's the first functioning code :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse_string(char *string);

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "Hello";
    reverse_string(string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 0;
}

void reverse_string(char *string)
{
    if (string == NULL) return;

    char *end = string;

    if (*end == '\0') return;

    while (*end != '\0') end++;

    end--;
    char *start = string;
    char temp;

    while (start < end)
    {
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}

And the other one :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse_string(char *string);

int main(void)
{
    char *string = "Hello";
    reverse_string(string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 0;
}

void reverse_string(char *string)
{
    if (string == NULL) return;

    char *end = string;

    if (*end == '\0') return;

    while (*end != '\0') end++;

    end--;
    char *start = string;
    char temp;

    while (start < end)
    {
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}

Thanks
Tried to search for clear explanations on the web but always came across explanations such as char *word = char word[]

This is false: “the char* type, which can also be written as char[]”. Do not believe things you read on the Internet. Evaluate the source. Use good textbooks and reference materials, not random sites you find. char [] is sometimes conflated with char * because of some automatic adjustments and conversions that occur in C, but they are distinctly different things with different properties. char [] is an array that contains characters. char * is a pointer that points to a char. You can point to the first char of an array and use them similarly, but they are different.

In C, there is no built in string type. Instead there is a standard convention that is used of how to handle strings using arrays of chars.

Because of the automatic adjustment of parameters, it can be somewhat reasonable to say that char [] and char * are the same in a parameter declaration. But we can see from the context of the passage you give, mentioning the size of an array, it is not appropriate in this situation. The automatic adjustment of a char [] declaration to char * means the size will not be passed. In addition, the sentence “For other array types, you're always obliged to retain the size of the array somewhere” is nonsense; this is the same for arrays of char as it is for other arrays.
